# Twitter python scraping

Tags: python, xpath

**My Code:**

```
from lxml import html
import requests
# you can use any website
page = requests.get('https://twitter.com/MarketWatch/lists/marketwatch-staff/members')
tree = html.fromstring(page.text)

#This will create a list of staff
staff=tree.xpath('//li[contains(@id,"user")]/div/div[2]/div/div/a/span/text()')

print 'Staff: ', staff
```

When I use above code, I am getting only 20 members in the list, but there are 89 members.

**My output:**

```
 InsecurePlatformWarning 
Staff:  ['@Craig_Tolliver', '@MarketsTicker', '@EnergyTicker', '@MWHealthBlog', '@KitchenNews', '@SueChangMW', '@MWMozee', '@jjelter', '@MKTWRetirement', '@ClaudiaAssisMW
', '@TomiKilgore', '@EllieIsma', '@capitolreport', '@elizobrien', '@SilviaAscarelli', '@wmwitkowski', '@MKTWeconomics', '@MKTWGraphics', '@JohnWordock', '@SAFmedia']
```

I need all 89 members list.

Comment: Why do you want to scrape this information and not use the [Twitter API](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/followers/ids)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you scrape it manually, the page shows the first 20 members and loads (by the use of a AJAX call) more members **dynamically**  if you scroll down. This behaviour does not happen when you perform a http request in python.

As Arkanosis and Odi already suggested, use the Twitter [API](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/lists/members) to make requests like these.

Comment: Great,But just want to scrap simple, How to get all members list from AJAX ? Is any code for AJAX ? I am ok with BeautifulSoup OR scarpy 

@DJanssens

Can u explain ,how to use API to get my member.
Pls give code or explain briefly

Answer (score 1):

Twitter has a [nice API](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/lists/members); I suggest you use it instead of trying to scrap the web site (which is more likely to change over time).